# Sharing Assets folder between front end and backend of ASP.NET MVC solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, subdomain

I've recently been put in charge of finishing a project that one of our former developers began building.

Basically what I'm trying to do is set up a path to a shared assets folder that will contain images to be shared and accessed via both the front and back ends which sit on the same domain.

The back end has the functionality to upload images to this shared folder to be displayed on the front end.

There are multiple environments - localhost , staging and the live site itself.

The previous dev created a Paths class to handle this however it seemed to duplicate the assets from the backend to the front end.

So the path I want to set is for the assets root directory which would be;

- localhost/sitename.com.au/Assets
- staging.sitename.com.au/Assets
- sitename.com.au/Assets

The problem is that if I use the ~/Assets it stays on the subdomain level and I need it to go up a level to the site root (see below)

Here's the current url structures:

**LOCAL DEV**

- localhost/sitename.com.au/Front-End Solution
- localhost/sitename.com.au/System.Administration Solution

**STAGING (TEST SERVER)**

- staging.subdomain.sitename.com.au
- staging.admin.sitename.com.au

**LIVE**

- subdomain.sitename.com.au
- admin.sitename.com.au

I'm only relatively new to this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Problem resolved using virtual directories (example.com/Assets) in each solution pointing to a central physical path (C:/.../application/SharedAssets)on IIS server.

Comment: add this comment as an aswer to your question. Otherwise, it remains categorized as opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved using virtual directories (example.com/Assets) in each solution pointing to a central physical path (C:/.../application/SharedAssets) on IIS server.